# Berkshelf - Dependencies from another git repo

Tags: berksfile

I have a cookbook which has a dependency to one of the opsworks cookbooks (in the git repo) which in turn has many dependencies defined in the metadata which also resides in the same repo.I have added the dependency in my cookbook metadata file. But when I run berks install it's able to resolve the my dependent cookbook but not it's dependencies. Please help me in writing the Berksfile which will resolve all the dependencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://sethvargo.com/berksfile-magic/ this has the answer for the above question.